# How to use convert for creation

Tags: type-conversion, eiffel

Using "Void safety - complete", my code:

```
class TENSOR_SHAPE
create
    default_create,
    from_tuple
convert
    from_tuple ({TUPLE [INTEGER]})
feature -- Initialization
    from_tuple (a_shape: TUPLE [INTEGER])
...
```

I try to call this with:

```
    local
        s: TENSOR_SHAPE
    do
        s := [2, 4, 3, 5]  -- convert from tuple?
```

I get "source of assignment is not compatible with target."

```
    Target name:  s
    Target type:  detachable TENSOR_SHAPE
    Source type:  attached TUPLE [INTEGER_32, ...]
on line "s := [2, 4, 3, 5]".
```

Why does the compiler say `s' is detachable?
Is this not how conversions are used?
thanks,
jjj

Answer (score 1):

`TUPLE [INTEGER]` `convert` declaration will be selected when argument is a tuple containing a single `INTEGER`, for example:

```
s := [2]
```

Now in order to handle `[2, 4, 3, 5]` a matching declaration is required:

```
convert
    from_tuple ({TUPLE [INTEGER, INTEGER, INTEGER, INTEGER]})
feature -- Initialization
    from_tuple (a_shape: TUPLE [INTEGER, INTEGER, INTEGER, INTEGER])
```

Also an interesting moment here is that `feature` may actually accept a tuple subtype with smaller amount of items, so the following example will also work:

```
convert
    from_tuple ({TUPLE [INTEGER, INTEGER, INTEGER, INTEGER]})
feature -- Initialization
    from_tuple (a_shape: TUPLE [INTEGER])
```

Comment: Okay.  But why then can I use " feature  make (a_tuple: TUPLE [INTEGER])" and call it with "create my_object.make ([1, 2, 3])"?

Comment: @jjj Because `TUPLE [INTEGER, INTEGER, INTEGER]` is an also an instance of `TUPLE [INTEGER, INTEGER]` and `TUPLE [INTEGER]`  (and just `TUPLE`)

Comment: So that conformaty applies to assignments and argument passing but not conversions?

Comment: @jjj Eiffel does not allow feature overloading (e.g. declaring `feature from_tuple (a_shape: TUPLE [INTEGER]) ... feature from_tuple (a_shape: TUPLE [INTEGER, INTEGER]) ... `). However  conversion operation may have several overloads and the exact match will be selected.

Comment: So the conversion feature `from_tuple (a_tuple: INTEGER)' could accept a TUPLE [INTEGER, INTEGER, ...] as argument because of conformity rules, but using that feature as a conversion routine require exact match?

Comment: @jjj Yes, looks like that.